# Ffmpeg in docker-compose could not be started

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, docker-compose

[image]

[image]

I have the following `docker-compose` file but my `ffmpeg` container does not seem to start for some reason. It outputs a code of `0` and does not give any other info.

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  b2c:
    driver: bridge

services:
  ffmpeg:
    container_name: b2c-ffmpeg
    image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg

  nginx:
    container_name: b2c-nginx
    image: nginx:1.17.0
    depends_on:
      - "php"
    volumes:
      - ../server/public:/server/public
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ../data/nginx/logs:/logs
    networks:
      - b2c
    ports:
      - "20001:80"

  php:
    container_name: b2c-php
    image: indexlin/gzyx-php7.2.4:1.1
    working_dir: /server
    volumes:
      - ../server:/server
      #- ./php/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    networks:
      - b2c
    ports:
      - "23001:9000"
    #user: "1000:1000"

  mysql:
    container_name: b2c-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ../data/mysql/lib:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ../data/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql
      - ./config/mysql/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    networks:
      - b2c
    ports:
      - "25001:3306"

  redis:
    container_name: b2c-redis
    image: redis:5.0.5
    volumes:
      - ../data/redis:/data
      - ./config/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      - b2c
    ports:
      - "27001:6379"

  node:
    container_name: b2c-node
    volumes:
      - ../server:/server
      - ../web:/web
    image: node:10.15.3
    networks:
      - b2c
    tty: true
    working_dir: /web
    ports:
      - "29001:29000"
```

Comment: b2c-ffmpeg exited with code 0

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
ffmpeg:
    container_name: b2c-ffmpeg
    image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg
    #tty: true
    networks:
      - b2c
    ports:
      - "29002:29000"
    tty: true
    entrypoint: "bash"
```

I have solved the problem.